# How to Change month number into words

Tags: php, laravel

This is the Code I use for the date

```
<div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label>Reservation Date</label>
                <input min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('0 years'));?>" type="date" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="reservation_date" required> 
            </div>
```

This is in the controller

```
$reservations->reservation_date = $request->input('reservation_date');
```

I want to search for a specific month instead of number how to search using word or either of the two like February/02..
This is the search code

```
$res = PropertyReservation::where('reservation_date', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
```

whats the way to do it

Comment: Can you show value format in `$search` and your table `reservation_date` field as well ??

Comment: use F instead of m in `<?php echo date('Y-m-d'` , it will take month in string value. [source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: @RohitMittal this is the search 
                @if(count($res) > 0)
                
                    @foreach($res as $ress) <td>{{$ress->reservation_date}}</td>

Comment: @Vishwa if i change it to F it still wont change

Comment: $date = date('Y-m-d');
echo date("F",strtotime($date));

Comment: why it will return Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: 'May-06-2019' for column 'reservation_date'

Comment: Can you print $search value and show me o/p of it?? Also share database sql value for reservation_date field